# tput: "No value for $TERM and no -T specified" when command run over ssh

Tags: shell, tput

I am running shell script from master node in the cluster on all other nodes as,

```
ssh root@"$node_name" 'bash -s' < ./script.sh
```

script.sh contains the following line which is used for formatting which adds horizontal line according to the size of the terminal,

```
printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
```

Which gives error and does not print the horizontal line,

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

But when I run it individually on each node, it does not give an error and prints horizontal line.

Comment: "But when I run it individually on each node" also as root?

Comment: Yes as root on each node.

Comment: You presumably have a TERM when you're running on the node

Comment: Setting `COLUMNS` makes no sense at all if there isn't a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option One: Making `ssh` provide a TTY

Pass `-tt` to ssh to force it to provide a TTY, and pass `TERM` through explicitly if you don't trust ssh to be configured to do so implicitly:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- the below printf usage is not available in baseline POSIX sh

printf -v term_q '%q' "$TERM"
ssh -t root@"$node_name" "TERM=$term_q bash -s" < ./script.sh
```

Of course, this only makes sense if your `ssh` is run from a terminal. If it's run from a cron job, then you need something different.

---

#### Option Two: Making Do Without One

The operation you're running is one that only makes sense in the context of a terminal. With no terminal, there doesn't *exist* a terminal width for `tput` to look up; and with no terminal type set via the `TERM` environment variable, there's no control sequence available for it to use.

Consider setting a default for noninteractive use:

```
# if we have no TERM, and no preexisting COLUMNS, set our own
[[ $TERM || $COLUMNS ]] || COLUMNS=80
```

...or writing your code to handle the case itself:

```
# skip this command altogether if we have no TERM or COLUMNS
[[ $TERM || $COLUMNS ]] && printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
```

(Note that assigning to `COLUMNS` is not particularly well-defined behavior; some shells may not allow it; they're well within the POSIX specification to do so, as the shell and system utilities are allowed to make their own use of all-caps variable names; only lower-case names are guaranteed safe for other applications to use).